# Unable to pass a parameter to an imported function in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having some trouble understanding why when I try to pass an object to an imported function, `getUserAlert`, one of the object's parameters (`user_id`) shows up as `undefined` in the function itself even when I have passed the values to the argument. Below is the code:

In `alerts.vue`

```
<script>
import { getUserAlert } from '@/lib/alerts.js'
import { mapGetters }  from 'vuex'

export default {

  data: function() {
    return {
      alerts: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("authentication",['token']),
    ...mapGetters("user",['profile']),
    displayAlerts() {
      console.log(this.profile.user_id) //The value of id appears at this point
      console.log(this.token) //The value of token appears
      return getUserAlert({
        profile: this.profile.user_id, 
        token: this.token
      }).then(response => (this.alerts = response.data))
    },
    anAlert() {
      return "ALERT"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In `alerts.js`

```
export let getUserAlert = ({ user_id, token }) => {
  console.log(user_id) //Shown as undefined
  console.log(token) //The value of token appears 
}
```

If I now change the `alert.js` file to:

```
export let getUserAlert = ({ user_id=123, token }) => {
  console.log(user_id) //Shows 123
  console.log(token) //The value of token appears 
}
```

Why is it that I need to pass an `user_id` value to the `getUserAlert` function within the function itself but not the `token`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in `getUserAlert` the wrong property has been destructured. What you need is `profile`.

Try as the following:

```
export let getUserAlert = ({ profile, token }) => {
  console.log(profile);
  console.log(token);
};
```

Or pass as `user_id`:

```
getUserAlert({
   user_id: this.profile.user_id, 
   token: this.token
});
```

Hope that helps!